# Three js, loading texture to only specific mtl

Tags: three.js

I am loading obj & mtl file using OBJMTLLoader. There are multiple materials in the object. What I want is to apply texture to a particular material within the object.

Eg. I have a Bag object, and it has Handle, Brand name, Wheels as different material. I want to add different texture to each of them. The texture will not be there in the material file. I want to add it using code only.

```
<pre>
    var loader = new THREE.OBJMTLLoader();
    loader.load( 'obj/Test.obj', 'obj/Test.mtl', function ( object ) {

    var tex = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({map:THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(     'obj/texture.png')});

    object.traverse( function(child) {
    if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
    // apply custom material
    child.material = tex;

    // enable casting shadows
    child.castShadow = true;
    child.receiveShadow = true;
    }
    });
</pre>
```

Comment: To do that I would first load the texture and then the model (ie put the loader.load function into the loadTexture callback). Also you need a test (your code would apply to all meshes). But for a unique file I would simply add the texture into the .MTL (just add 'map_Ka path/textureimage.jpg' to the material definition), at least if I don't need to control wrap paramaters...

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by checking the name of the material that you have written in your mtl file and then assigning the texture.

Your .mtl file looks like this:

```
newmtl wheels
Ka  1.0 1.0 1.0
Kd  1.0 1.0 1.0
d  1.0
# ...
```

and in code:

```
var wheelsTexture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('obj/wheelTexture.png');

object.traverse( function(child) {
    if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
        if ( child.material.name === "wheels" ) {

            child.material.map = wheelsTexture;

        } else if ( child.material.name === "handle" ) {
            // ...
        }
    }
} );
```